# ScrollView not working with Tabbed layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-tabactivity

I am a newbie to Android and I am trying to use a ScrollView in the Tabbed layout. When I include the fragment layout to the tabbed view, the last element is not showing when we scroll down. I tried setting the height of the "LinearLayout" to "wrap_content" but still it is not working.

Ideally I needed only one button, other button are added just for testing purposes.

**The same layout is working fine if I add it to an Activity and not a Tab view.**

Here is the layout which contains a ScrollView

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:context="com.adroitminds.tabbedview.Section2">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="First Name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Last Name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="First Name1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Last Name2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Phone2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Email2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Phone" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Email" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Password" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Confirm Password" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Submit" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Submit1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Submit2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Tabbed Activity which has the issue

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Here are the screenshots for both scenarois

**Fragment in an Activity - working fine**
[image: Activity - working]

**Fragment in an Tabbed layout - not working**
[image: TabView - not working]

I can resolve this issue by reducing the margins or size of the EditTexts, but I am curious to know where I am going wrong.Could anyone please help me resolving this issue.

I am using latest version of Android Studio
**minSdkVersion - 18

targetSdkVersion - 23**

Thanks,
Kapil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your `ScrollView` :

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Also remove the same attribute from **android.support.v4.view.ViewPager**
The ViewPager should be

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint mate. Apart from your answer I had to remove that attribute from **android.support.v4.view.ViewPager** as well

Comment: Glad I could help. :)