# ScrollView not working properly with tabbed activity

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, tabs, scrollview

I am creating an activity with tabs and view pager. I used the default tabbed activity template provided by android studio to create it. My problem is that I am not able add scroll to fragments layout added in view pager.
I read from this link [Add ScrollView to Tab Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33354845/scrollview-not-working-with-tabbed-layout-in-android)

and removed this 
`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`.

But when I added this line to scrollview my tabs and action bar were also gone.I have already added my fragment in scrollview but it doesn't work .

Here is my main and fragment xml

Main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.webninjaz.kirti.dnschanger.activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#5A595B"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="DNS CHANGER"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#727272"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ccc"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/TopHeader"
                        android:text="Current WIFI Info"
                        android:paddingRight="15dp"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:baselineAligned="false">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".50"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"
                        android:id="@+id/WiFiConnectLeft"
                        android:text="Wifi Name :"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"
                        android:id="@+id/DefaultGatewayLeft"
                        android:text="Default Gateway :"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"
                        android:id="@+id/DNS1Left"
                        android:text="Primary DNS :"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"
                        android:id="@+id/DNS2Left"
                        android:text="Secondary DNS :"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"
                        android:id="@+id/CurrentIPLeft"
                        android:text="IP Address :"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".50"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:id="@+id/WiFiConnectedText"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"
                        android:text=""/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/DefaultGatewayText"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/DNS1Text"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/DNS2Text"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/CurrentIPText"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CHANGE DNS"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:id="@+id/MiddleHeaderText"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/lin_primary"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="15dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/primary"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:id="@+id/PrimaryDNSText"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:textSize="13sp"/>
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.2"
                    android:background="#000"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:maxLength="16"
                    android:id="@+id/EDITDNS1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=""/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8"
                    android:text="BROWSE"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_click"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:id="@+id/BrowseDNS1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lin_primary"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/lin_secondary"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="15dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/secondary"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:id="@+id/SecondaryDNSText"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.2"
                    android:background="#000"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:maxLength="16"
                    android:id="@+id/EDITDNS2"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=""
                    />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8"
                    android:text="BROWSE"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_click"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:id="@+id/BrowseDNS2"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/UpdateDNS"
                    android:text="Update"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_click"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ResetWifi"
                    android:text="RESET"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_click"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add this in line in scroll view and delete from view pager.
    Scroll view may be like this.

```
   <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

Comment: this also removes tabs and title bar

Comment: can you tell me which device you are using for testing because i am running on 5.1 version of 5.5 screen size and its working good.

Comment: sony xperia kitkat 4.4.4

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this to linear layout:

```
android:paddingBottom="100dp"
```

Seems the Viewpager/container view is set to be larger than the device screen somewhere.